# Angular dart - custom input component with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I'm trying to create a custom input text component but I don't know how to make it work with the `ngModel` directive.

I've tried replicating the [material angular_component input](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/a09df6f76c681e68efc2dc82c837070105340ead/angular_components/lib/material_input/base_material_input.dart) but can't understand how the `inputText` property is actually linked to the `ngModel` value and what is the purpose of `DefaultValueAccessor` directive.

This is how I expect to use my component:

```html
<my-input-component [(ngModel)]="someProp"><my-input-component>
```

*(where the content of `my-input-component` is just a plain `<input type="text">` field with  a label)*

Any ideas or links to examples/docs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think so, since you cannot make Input() and Output() with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the angular_components code, I found the answer myself. You have to implement `ControlValueAccessor` and to register the `ngValueAccessor` provider (that actually was the missing part).

Here is my solution:

```dart
// my_custom_component.dart
@Component(
  selector: 'my-custom-component',
  templateUrl: '<div class="input-wrapper">{{value}}</div>',
  providers: [
    ExistingProvider.forToken(ngValueAccessor, MyCustomComponent),
  ],
)
class MyCustomComponent implements ControlValueAccessor<String> {
  String value;
  // ...could define a setter that call `_changeController.add(value)`

  final _changeController = StreamController<String>();

  @Output()
  Stream<String> get onChange => _changeController.stream;

  @override
  void writeValue(String newVal) {
    value = newVal ?? '';
  }

  @override
  void registerOnChange(callback) {
    onChange.listen((value) => callback(value));
  }

  // optionally you can implement the rest interface methods
  @override
  void registerOnTouched(TouchFunction callback) {}

  @override
  void onDisabledChanged(bool state) {}
}
```

```dart
// app_component.dart
@Component(
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: '''
    <my-custom-component [(ngModel)]="data"></my-custom-component>
  ''',
  directives: [
    NgModel,
    MyCustomComponent,
  ],
)
class AppComponent {
  String data;
}
```

*Note: angular_component uses directives but the main idea is the same.*